# Adding indices for columns

Tags: matlab, vector, cell

`data_2` is a cell containing `date` in the first column and `time` in the second column. Whenever there is an object detected under a time stamp, the identity of the object along with the error is added to the next row. (This data is from video recordings of toy cars).

What i want to do is to add increasing index number corresponding to each time stamp. In the sample code shown, i am adding the index to the first column. I wrote a sample code to perform this. When i perform this, the increasing index is also added for detections under a single time stamp.

Eg: If you look at `row 5` there are two detections and the identities are added to the rows 6 and 7. These both are detected at same time. But there frame number is not the same. It should be the same as of the time stamp, ie `5`. Any help to solve this will be appreciated.

```
 data_2 = {'2018-03-11','15:28:30';'2018-03-11','15:28:32';'2018-03-11','15:28:34';'2018-03-11','15:28:36';'2018-03-11','15:28:38';'27','0';'29','1';'2018-03-11','15:28:40';'2018-03-11','15:28:42';'2018-03-11','15:28:44';'89','2'};
 frame_num_2 = strsplit(num2str(1:size(contains(data_2(:,1),'-'))))';   
 data_2 = [frame_num_2 data_2];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want the frame number to increase by one only when there is a new date or time, and not when you have an object detected. 
To address this, you need to detect when a row is a date or time. Looking at your data, what is distinct about the date column is the presence of '-', and what is distinct about the time column is the presence of ':'.  You can use either or both of these, I chose to use only the date column.

```
data_date = data_2(:,1);
data_time = data_2(:,2);
%data that doesn't have a new frame contains a '-' symbol.  
newFrame = contains(data_date, '-');
frame_num = cumsum(newFrame); %only increase when there is a new frame
Data = [num2cell(frame_num) data_2] %save in a new variable name
```

which results in Data =

```
{[1]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:30'}
{[2]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:32'}
{[3]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:34'}
{[4]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:36'}
{[5]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:38'}
{[5]}    {'27'        }    {'0'       }
{[5]}    {'29'        }    {'1'       }
{[6]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:40'}
{[7]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:42'}
{[8]}    {'2018-03-11'}    {'15:28:44'}
{[8]}    {'89'        }    {'2'       }
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted.